# how to turn a matrix into a sparse matrix and protobuf it

Tags: numpy, scipy, sparse-matrix, amazon-sagemaker, matrix-factorization

I have a data set with 16 columns and 100,000 rows which I'm trying to prepare for a matrix-factorization training. I'm using the following code to split it and turn it into a sparse matrix.

```
X=data.drop([data.columns[0]],axis='columns')
y=data[[1]]
X=lil_matrix(100000,15).astype('float32')
y=np.array(y).astype('float32')
X
```

But when I run it, I get this error:

> <1x1 sparse matrix of type ''  with 1 stored
>   elements in LInked List format> .

When I try to plug it into a training/testing split it gives me further errors:

> Found input variables with inconsistent numbers of samples: [1,
>   100000]

Comment: In Python each of those assignments is independent.  Assigning the `lil` to `X` replaces the previous `data.drop` assignment.  And your `lil_matrix` call does not conform to the documentation.  Reread https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.sparse.lil_matrix.html

Comment: I still don't understand what is it doing to the data tbh. they don't have an example and that makes it frustrating . when I try to print the data it says its 1 stored element. can u pls elaborate if you understand it? thanks

Comment: I can't tell what you are trying do.  What's the source of this code, or at least its inspiration.  What's the source of `data`.  What is it?

Comment: just trying to apply my data on this tutorial basically . but when I do the lil sparse method it turns it into 1 value. I don't understand it..https://github.com/juliensimon/dlnotebooks/blob/master/sagemaker/03-Factorization-Machines-Movielens.ipynb

Comment: You aren't using the `lil_matrix` call in the same way.  Did you even check the documentation link that I gave you?  I see bits and pieces that you might have borrowed from that tutorial, but nothing consistent.  Modifying tutorials with a limited knowledge of the underlying language (and modules) can be frustrating.

Comment: Any suggestions ? I didnt post to be criticized b JT for advice

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your linked `notebook` is creating a 'blank' sparse matrix, and setting selected elements from data it reads from a `csv`.

A simple example of this:

```
In [565]: from scipy import sparse                                                                           
In [566]: M = sparse.lil_matrix((10,5), dtype=float)                                                         
In [567]: M                                                                                                  
Out[567]: 
<10x5 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.float64'>'
    with 0 stored elements in LInked List format>
```

Note that I use `(10,5)` to specify the matrix shape.  The () matter!  That's why I stressed reading the `docs`.  In the link the relevant line is:

```
X = lil_matrix((lines, columns)).astype('float32')
```

Now I can set a couple elements, just as I would an dense array:

```
In [568]: M[1,2] = 12.3                                                                                      
In [569]: M[3,1] = 1.1                                                                                       
In [570]: M                                                                                                  
Out[570]: 
<10x5 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.float64'>'
    with 2 stored elements in LInked List format>
```

I can use `toarray` to display the matrix as a dense array (don't try this with large dimensions).

```
In [571]: M.toarray()                                                                                        
Out[571]: 
array([[ 0. ,  0. ,  0. ,  0. ,  0. ],
       [ 0. ,  0. , 12.3,  0. ,  0. ],
       [ 0. ,  0. ,  0. ,  0. ,  0. ],
       [ 0. ,  1.1,  0. ,  0. ,  0. ],
       [ 0. ,  0. ,  0. ,  0. ,  0. ],
       [ 0. ,  0. ,  0. ,  0. ,  0. ],
       [ 0. ,  0. ,  0. ,  0. ,  0. ],
       [ 0. ,  0. ,  0. ,  0. ,  0. ],
       [ 0. ,  0. ,  0. ,  0. ,  0. ],
       [ 0. ,  0. ,  0. ,  0. ,  0. ]])
```

---

If I omit the (), it makes a (1,1) matrix with just one element, the first number.

```
In [572]: sparse.lil_matrix(10,5)                                                                            
Out[572]: 
<1x1 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.int64'>'
    with 1 stored elements in LInked List format>
In [573]: _.A                                                                                                
Out[573]: array([[10]], dtype=int64)
```

Look again at your code.  You set the `X` value twice, once it is a dataframe.  The second time is this bad `lil` initialization.  The second time does not make use of the first `X`.

```
X=data.drop([data.columns[0]],axis='columns')
...
X=lil_matrix(100000,15).astype('float32')
```

Comment: thank you! ya I finally found some examples that helped and this helped too . so I understood what lil_ matrix does with it. all im trying to do is turn my matrix into spaese so I can protobuf it cuz aws would not accept the data in CSV format. it just keeps rejecting it. so that's what it is this about really .. if you have any input on that its appreciated! thanks for the detailed example- it helps. scypi has very little on sparse matrices and no examples- boo

Comment: so i used this instead of to read the data -data=np.genfromtxt('The_Data_for_channel.csv',delimiter=',') then i split it like this X=data[:,1:]
y=data[:,0:1]
X=X.astype('float32')
y=y.astype('float32')  then i tried this simpler way to protobuf it but it gives ms valuer error : Labels must be a Vector
this code actually sparsed it X=lil_matrix(X) but it still gives me the error that is not a vector.

Comment: the preceeding error code is this. i think i m 1 and dont understand why its raising an error..   if labels is not None:
     95         if not len(labels.shape) == 1:
---> 96             raise ValueError("Labels must be a Vector")
     97         if labels.shape[0] not in array.shape:
     98             raise ValueError("Label shape {} not compatible with array shape {}".format(